# Not able to display a button inside ng-accordian tag

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

i am using ngb-accordian to display accordians whenever a search text is found.
now my requirement is to add a button on the heading. clicking on which will take me to another component.

the code in HTML goes like :

```
<ngb-accordion   #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0"> 
<ngb-panel [title]='(metadata.topic)?"Topic: "+metadata.topic:
(metadata.item)?"Product: "+metadata.item:"EMPTY"' *ngFor="let metadata of 
filteredData">
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<ng-template ngbPanelContent>

  <ul>
      <li *ngFor='let key of metadata | keys'>
       {{key.key}} : {{key.value}}
      </li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

i am new to angular and bootstrap please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `ngb-panel` add a `ng-template` tag like below

```
<ngb-accordion> 
    <ngb-panel>
        <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
            <button>Button Text</button>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```